# Spring Boot REST: Sort direction is ignored, but Sort generally works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing an REST API with Spring Boot. Therefore I get employees by Name. I am passing the `Pageable` parameter for sorting, the problem is the direction is ignored. So Spring always sorts `asc` nerve `desc`, which is the default behavior. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I need to add, that sorting in general is working, because if I don't pass the `chrValue` as `sort` parameter, I get items like they are stored in the DB.

The Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/search/findDimensionAttributeValueByDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeID?dimensionAttributeId=1&page=0&size=1&sort=chrValue&chrValue.dir=desc
```

The Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "dimensionAttributeValue", path = "dimensionAttributeValues")
@CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders="Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
public interface DimensionAttributeValueRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DimensionAttributeValue, Long> {
    Page<DimensionAttributeValue> findDimensionAttributeValueByDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeID(@Param(value = "dimensionAttributeId") long dimensionAttributeId, Pageable pageable);
    Page<DimensionAttributeValue> findDimensionAttributeValueByMasterDataMasterDataIDAndDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeID(@Param(value = "masterDataId") long masterDataId, @Param(value = "dimensionAttributeId") long dimensionAttributeId, Pageable pageable);
    Page<DimensionAttributeValue> findDimensionAttributeValueByDimensionAttributeDimensionDimensionIDOrDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeIDOrderByChrValue(@Param(value="dimensionID") long dimensionID, @Param(value = "dimensionAttributeID") long dimensionAttributeID, Pageable pageable);
    Page<DimensionAttributeValue> findAllByDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeIDAndChrValueStartingWith(@Param(value = "dimensionAttributeId") long dimensionID, @Param(value = "chrValue") String chrValue, Pageable pageable);

}
```

The Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DimensionAttributeValue")
public class DimensionAttributeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "DimensionAttributeValue_ID")
    private long dimensionAttributeValueID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DimensionAttribute_ID")
    private DimensionAttribute dimensionAttribute;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MasterData_ID")
    private MasterData masterData;

    @Column (name = "ChrValue")
    private String chrValue;

    @Column (name = "IntValue")
    private Long intValue;

    @Column (name = "DecValue")
    private Double decValue;

    @Column (name = "DatValue")
    private String datValue;

    @Column (name = "BlnValue")
    private Boolean blnValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "LnkValue")
    private DimensionAttributeValue lnkValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "LstValue")
    private DimensionAttributeList lstValue;

    @Column (name = "StartDate")
    private Date startDate;

    // [...]
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that the url params are case sensetive? Since your Column name is "ChrValue" with a capital C and your param is chrValue.

Comment: Good idea, I tried that, but same behavior. Also I think spring always uses the attribute names.

Comment: In your request you pass size=1 is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but I have the same behavior with size=20 oder size=200.

Comment: @Max Try this. `http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/search/findDimensionAttributeValueByDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeID?dimensionAttributeId=1&page=0&size=1&sort=chrValue,desc`

Comment: Thanks thats works! i read my version `&sort=chrValue&chrValue.dir=desc` in docs. Seams like a read the wrong version. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya add your answer as solution, than i can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this URL .

`http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/search/findDimensionAttributeValueByDimensionAttributeDimensionAttributeID?dimensionAttributeId=1&page=0&size=1&sort=chrValue,desc`.

This will sort your data in descending Order.